# Navigation incompatible for IE 8

Tags: html, css, ie8-compatibility-mode

I don't know why this not working properly on ie8.

[image]

```
<div id="bluemenu" class="bluetabs">
<ul>
<li class="">
  <a rel="dropmenu3_c" href="company/">Company 
    <span><img width="11"height="7" src="images/arrow_btn.png"></span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This is the css for the navigation ul

```
.bluetabs ul {
color: #FFFFFF;
float: right;
font: 13px 'Open Sans','Lucida Grande',Arial,"Verdana sans-serif";
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
text-align: left;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

This is the css for the navigation li

```
.bluetabs li {
display: inline;
float: left;
height: 36px;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
```

This is the css for the navigation li a

```
.bluetabs li a {
background: url("../images/menu_nav_hover_bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 0;
padding: 5px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Any CSS hacks that I can make this work on IE 8?

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: Elsewhere in your CSS do you have something like `img { display: block }`?

Comment: Thank you for your comments, really appreciate it. davidpauljunior answer is awesome!!

Answer (score 1):

I can kind of reproduce this locally, but not entirely.
Gonna take a shot in the dark...

Try:

```
.bluetabs li a {
  background: #ccc;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block; /* Add this */
}

/* Add this */
.bluetabs li a > span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I'm glad it worked!  Don't forgot to mark the answer correct, thanks!